# Highlight or identify certain characters in php / css, where data originates from CSV?

Tags: php, csv, utf-8

I've built a web page that parses a CSV file to pull information into a web page, and display the results in a certain design. CSV is used because the data originates as an Excel file into which I import data from several sources, and combine it into the one CSV file which I upload to my web server whenever there is a change in data.

Presumably because it's parsing the CSV file, I occasionally get a UTF-8 error in the data shown, and unsupported characters such as `–`, `’`, `⌀` characters are displayed as ࠀ.  I've tried to prevent this as much as possible, by saving down the CSV in UTF-8 encoding.  If these aren't noticed, they will cause a problem later in my workflow when I save down the data from the web page.  To prevent this happening and make it easy for me to notice, I want to be able to have some way of identifying these characters on the web page.

How can I identify the ࠀ or � symbols and somehow highlight the fact they exist on the page? I've thought of some methods but don't know how to implement them simply - for instance:

- JavaScript that provides a big red error message at the top of the page with a count of how many of those characters there are.
- CSS that targets those characters, and highlights them: changes the font color etc.
- Buffer the web page, and then use `str_replace` to add inline CSS to highlight as above.

Are any of these worth exploring, or is there a solution that's better?  I don't think I've seen any � characters since I changed everything to UTF-* but would still like to look out for them.

Here's the code snippet:

```html
<?php
$irand = mt_rand(10000,100000000);
if($code!=''){
    $ch = fopen("https://sampleurl.co.uk/thedata.csv?ver=$irand", "r");
    // $file = fopen('http://localhost/stackoverflow/test.csv', 'r');
    while (($line = fgetcsv($ch)) !== FALSE) {
      $line = array_map("utf8_encode", $line); //added
      //$line is an array of the csv elements
      if($line[0]==$code){ // Here `0` indicate product_code column number and comparing with product_code number
          $product_code_array = $line;
      }
    }
    $no0 = $product_code_array[0];
    $no1 = $product_code_array[1];
    $no2 = $product_code_array[2];
    $no3 = $product_code_array[3];
    $no4 = $product_code_array[4];
    $no5 = $product_code_array[5];
    $no6 = $product_code_array[6];
    $no7 = $product_code_array[7];
    $no8 = $product_code_array[8];
    $no9 = $product_code_array[9];
    $no10 = $product_code_array[10];
    $no11 = $product_code_array[11];
    $no12 = $product_code_array[12];
    $no13 = $product_code_array[13];
    $no14 = $product_code_array[14];
    $no15 = $product_code_array[15];
    // [ removed as this code is the same all the way to #50 ] 
    $no50 = $product_code_array[50];
    fclose($ch);
}
?>
```

And any string that contains the mentioned characters will cause this error.  As an example, if this string is in the CSV:

`Item 01 – doesn’t work`

using `echo` or `print` will render it as:

`Item 01 ࠀ doesnࠀt work`

The main problem being that Office applications change `-` to `–` and in French, `'` is changed automatically to `’` in certain words.  Also some items such as `⌀` do not appear to be supported.  I'm sure there are other examples, but these are the ones I most commonly come across.

EDIT: I wanted to add an additional example.  The below code, when run on my server, results in this:

`Hereࠀs an example ࠀ dia. 25mm âࠀࠀ`

```css
        @font-face {
        font-family: "custom-helvetica";
        src: url("/assets/HelveticaNeue.ttf");
        src: url("/assets/HelveticaNeueBold.ttf");
        src: url("/assets/HelveticaBlkIt.ttf");
        }
        
        @font-face {
        font-family: "custom-tahoma";
        src: url("/assets/Tahoma.ttf");
        src: url("/assets/Tahomabd.ttf");
        }
        
        html {
            font-family: Tahoma, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            font-weight:normal;
            font-style:normal;
            }
```

```html
    <html>
    <p>Here’s an example – dia. 25mm ⌀</p>
    </html>
```

Edit 2: the web page contains the usual utf-8 declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE PHP>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Comment: Is the HTML file serving as UTF8? Why output to HTML to `save down the data from the web page`, can't the original CSV just be used?

Comment: Yes, the php / html is formatted as UTF-8 and defines UTF-8 charset in header.  Not sure it affects the question, but I'm outputting to HTML because through a lot of trial and error I've found it's the best way to present the data in a consistent manner in an exact design, style and format for my purposes.  I tried a lot of other methods but only PHP / CSS gave me the control and consistency I required.

Comment: What are you reading the CSV with? Can you please add code snippet, and original string that gets misrepresented?

Comment: @user3783243 Have updated the question with more detail, thanks for pointing out.

Comment: hi, have you tested htmlentities function?

Comment: @kraysak I've looked at this, not sure how it could help me though - can you elaborate?

Comment: Is your UTF-8 data _wrong_, does your application not support it, or is it getting mangled in the middle? If your UTF-8 encoded data is wrong, you've got a bad data in, bad data out problem. But I don't think that's it. Next up, is your entire pipleline UTF-8 aware? For instance, are you writing to a database or temporary file, or using an string manipulation functions? To test these things, you should be inspecting the byte stream looking for [`u+FFFD`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Specials_(Unicode_block)#Replacement_character) and trying to tackle the problem there.

Comment: @ChrisHaas when I check the CSV contents in the cpanel file manager, all the glyphs are correctly shown.  I've shown in the question the code I use to parse the CSV on the fly - fgetcsv(), write contents into variables, and echo those variables in the webpage.  I don't write the data to a temp database  or file.

Comment: @ChrisHaas Regards UTF-8 pipeline, I had a lot of � symbols until I made sure every file used UTF-8 as default.  Now I save the CSV as UTF-8, the upload form uses `accept-charset="utf-8"`, the webpage is declared as UTF-8 too (see edit 2 in the question), and since I've done that I think I've only seen the � symbol once.  But the ࠀ symbol keeps popping up.

Comment: Please confirm, you are just looking for a way to highlight these rouge characters, you are not looking to identify the cause? I ask because I have a feeling that the line `$line = array_map("utf8_encode", $line); //added` could be the cause. If your source file is UTF-8 then I don't think you want to encode it again. You should just be able to read it in and write it back out. I tried your code with and without that line, without the line it prints correctly, with it I get random characters. If you are just looking to identify them then I could try write some code to achieve that.

Comment: @5Diraptor The � is a replacement character and it `used to replace an incoming character whose value is unknown or unrepresentable in Unicode` - that means there is something wrong with the data. The ࠀ is a glyph... not a character per se and used (usually) as a standard way to represented the character that can't be rendered with the current font. So if you say that the text in the snippet wrongly rendered on your machine... that is not the case on my ubuntu. Maybe you use some old versions of fonts?

Comment: @Mark - interesting, I'm going to check that out.  I wanted to just identify the characters as I didn't think there was a way of getting rid of them, but getting rid of them would be the best!  Let me do some testing.

Comment: @x00 It's possible I use old fonts, but I've specified fallback fonts so pretty sure the browser should deal with if it was just a font issue?  or not?  it's another good point.

Comment: @Mark you are _the_ man :)  I commented out that line and tested all the weird glyphs that I could find and they came out perfectly.  Feel free to write your comment into an answer so I can close this.  Don't think I need to bother with identifying the rogue glyphs so don't worry about the extra code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my comment earlier that was tested and confirmed by @5Diraptor:

Because the CSV is saved down as utf-8 the line `$line = array_map("utf8_encode", $line); //added` would try to re-encode characters that it thinks are ISO-8859-1 into utf-8 therefore generating the weird glyphs experienced.

Removing that line appears to have resolved the issue.